# Methods For Estimating Trend in R

Tags: r, logistic, trend

Do you know how i can get a code for estimating trend by Mitcherlich and logistic method in R?

Comment: (1) Please give a link so we know what you're talking about and (2) Please make sure you have spelled the name correctly.

Comment: Also, this looks like it belongs on StackOverflow, since it is about R.

Comment: @PeterFlom While I agree that's how it looks, I think it's fairly likely to turn into a more clearly statistical question; I'd like to see more clarification first.

Comment: @user24955 Please check the parts in the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) that relate to what is on topic and how to ask good questions and try to edit your question to make it clearly on topic and make what you're asking for as explicit as possible. Please don't assume statisticians know any biology or soil science.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it just asks for a quick reference to specific R code, without much statistical background on the why and how. Despite some efforts made by active users on this site to help clarify what's being asked (+1 to the current reply), I believe this question needs some polishing to fit our posting policy. Feel free to vote to re-open when you are ready to do so.

Answer (score 2):

This rather extensive request for clarification plus the available information I could find will hopefully turn into a more complete answer when we have more information. I see two main possibilities -

**(A) Plant Growth**

I found this paper on plant growth:

http://www.wseas.us/e-library/transactions/biology/2007/25-645.pdf

which suggests that the deterministic *Mitscherlich* (note the spelling) growth law is:

$$K + (X_0-K)e^{-\frac{r}{K}(t-r_0)} \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)$$

where the response might be some measure of size, for example, *breast height diameter*, and that the Mitschelich steady state density (as solution to the Fokker-Planck equation) is:

$$N_s x^{-2\left(\frac{r}{K\sigma^2}+1\right)}e^{-2\frac{r}{\sigma^2x}} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (2)$$

where the normalizing constant

$$N_s = \left(\frac{2r}{\sigma^2}\right)\frac{2r}{K\sigma^2}/\Gamma\left(\frac{2r}{K\sigma^2}+1\right)$$

The article itself doesn't make life much easier, for example, by misspelling "Fokker-Planck" (!).

Is one of those two things the object you're talking about? If so, which one?

i.e. are you trying to fit either an equation describing the mean to data (expression (1)), or are you trying to fit a distribution that changes over time (expression (2))?

---

**(B) Crop Yield**

I also found this page on crop yield:

http://soil-statistic.de/mitscherlichs-law/mitscherlich.html

which has

$$\hat y = c + (a-c)(1-e^{-bx})$$

---

Are you trying to fit one of these? Or some other functional form?

If you're trying to fit the expression (1) in (A) or the equation in (B), what are you assuming about the error term? Does it have constant variance?

Please note that if your question is merely something like "*What do I type to fit a specific equation using* `nls` *in* `R`?*" it is off topic for CV, but probably on-topic for StackOverflow and will likely be closed or moved (indeed you can flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be moved yourself).

If that's the case, the check the asymptotic and asymptotic-with-offset models (which have self-start functions, `SSasymp` and `SSasympOff`) in `nls` and the logistic model which has self-start function `SSlogis` in `nls`.

Both 
expression (1) in (A) and the equation in (B) are closely related to the first two functions (try a little reparameterizing!), and various forms of the logistic model can be parameterized to the logistic one that already has a self-start function.

Using these models and self-start functions is described pretty well in the nonlinear models appendix to Fox's Companion to Applied Regression, [here](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendix/Appendix-Nonlinear-Regression.pdf) - there's also an older version at CRAN, [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-nonlinear-regression.pdf)

You may also like to check the documentation for `nls` and also the packages `nlstools` and `nls2`.