# Modern approaches to nonlinear regression which are available in R

Tags: r, least-squares, nonlinear-regression

I would like to fit a complex nonlinear regression model: basically, I have a complex computer code which has an input vector $\mathbf{x}$, a vector of calibration parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ and produces an output $s=f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\theta})$. I also have iid observations $y$ for this output, which I model as contaminated by Gaussian, zero mean noise:

$$y = f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\theta})+\epsilon$$

Let $D=\{\mathbf{x}_i,y_i\}_{i=1}^N$ be the data set of my observations. I would like to find the vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ which maximizes the likelihood of observing $D$. Because of the assumption I made on the noise, maximizing the likelihood is equivalent to minimizing the residual sum of squares. This means which I can find $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ by means of Nonlinear Least Squares.

I need to use R for this project. In R, `nls` is available to implement NLS, which I think implements the Newton algorithm, but I've had convergence issues using it. Also, the interface is (for me) a bit awkward.

Are there other methods for Nonlinear Least Square regression, which are readily available in R, and have better convergence properties?

**EDIT** I already received great suggestions (`nsl2`, `nlstools` and `nlmrt`) which may hopefully solve my issues. Anyway, I'm providing some extra details on my case. $f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\theta})$ is a black box, i.e., it's the output of a computer code for which I don't have the source. Thus I can't provide you with an analytical, explicit expression for $f(\mathbf{x},\boldsymbol{\theta})$. I can tell you that the code computes damping and stiffness for a particular kind of [turbomachinery seal](http://turbolab.tamu.edu/proc/turboproc/T22/T223-15.pdf),  by numerically integrating the 1D isothermal compressible Navier-Stokes equations in an annular geometry. The code has been tested and validated multiple times in the course of years, so it's reliable.

Parametrization: to respond to @Roland's comment, the code is an executable with an input file, which contains many input values. Among these values, with the support of seal experts I chose some values to be predictors (vector $\mathbf{x}$) and some others to be calibration parameters (vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$). Of course, since I don't have access to the code source, I cannot be sure that my parameters will be identifiable. But I think there must be a way to at least get an idea: I cannot open the code, but I can run it multiple times, for arbitrary values of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ (as long as the code converges :) Can this knowledge be used to address @Roland's points? I.e.,

1. whether the data support the problem (I don't understand this point)
2. if I need to reparametrize (this is clear and I think it's related to identifiability)
3. if I have a partial linear problem (what's this?)

**EDIT2** sadly I don't have access to gradients. It's a '70 code, and writing adjoint codes was not at all common in the engineering community at that time.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but it often does the trick for me when I have issues with nls models. The nlxb function from the nlmrt package more or less runs the same model but with brute force, it may help to find better start values and perhaps fix your problem. nlxb requires the exact same input as nls.

Comment: We have a number of threads where people discuss nls convergence problems which sometimes turn out to be solvable with the ordinary function, by either getting decent starting points, reparameterizing, or by changing some of the convergence settings. Some existing threads discuss possible alternatives or packages which contain helpful functions. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... For example [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57456/methods-for-estimating-trend-in-r/57460#57460) mentions `nls2` and `nlstools` (the first for example can brute force a fit and the second can help in choosing good start values). [This one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261010/fit-model-to-density-function-by-regression-improvements/261293#261293) mentions `nlmrt` and `nls2`. You don't seem to be asking anything new not already covered by several such threads, and you don't give enough information to suggest anything novel outside general kinds of advice.

Comment: There are many implementations of non-linear least squares and even more numeric optimizers available as packages. However, without knowing more about your specific function and its properties, it's not possible to make a good recommendation. Note that if `nls` doesn't converge and the reason is not bad starting values, you should usually spend more time considering the maths behind your problem. Maybe your data doesn't support the model, maybe you need to re-parameterize the model, maybe you have a partial linear problem and can use an algorithm utilizing that, maybe ...

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for the links.  What search did you use to find them ? `Nonlinear least squares [r]` finds mostly stuff on generalized nonlinear least squares. Your link are very useful - the other packages mentioned provide additional capability in choosing starting values which is precious when you don't have access to the stats model as in my case. I will add details on my question later on.

Comment: @Glen_b PS: IMO, an element of novelty in my case is that I don't have an analytical expression for the statistical model - my regression model is actually my closed source computer code (plus of course the assumption of iid Gaussian noise). I will try to add details later on.

Comment: @Delta I don't recall my exact searches; I didn't use the [r] tag. I may have used `nls2` among my search terms on at least one of my searches though, since I recall thinking that would find some of the other packages as well. I may have searched on "starting" or "convergence"; at least those were what I had planned to search on but  I don't recall how far I got through my list of things to search before I found enough to talk about. ... on the novelty of your problem, I'm not sure how you even specify the model to nls in that case.

Comment: @Glen_b you need to write a wrapper, i.e., a function which receives $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ as an input and returns the corresponding likelihood. Inside, the wrapper prepares $N$ input files for the computer code (as many as there are points in the data set), launches the code  $N$ times (with `system()`, reads the $N$ outputs and computes the likelihood. An hassle, really.

Comment: @Roland I don't have access to model, that's why I cannot go the usual way of looking at the model equations and determine the right parametrization. But surely there must be some indirect approach? See my edit.

Comment: There are of course optimizers with more robust convergence, though often false convergence or finding local minima. I assume that you don't have a gradient function? Anyway, you should go through the [Task View Optimization](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optimx/index.html).You could probably do worse than trusting JC Nash and using package nlmrt.

Comment: First try `nls` and if that works you are done.  If that gives you problems try the approach in the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511278/nls-curve-fit-singular-matrix-error/42513058#42513058

Comment: @DeltaIV I understand the general principle of how to perform the least squares calculation/calculate the likelihood in that situation (I've done that before in different computing environments); what I mean is I don't understand how you get `nls` to work that way, since it expects a formula argument (which it then operates on to evaluate the function, to calculate sums of squared errors and so on). Are you just writing something like `y ~ f(x,theta)`  where `f` is your wrapper?

Comment: @Glen_b yes, exactly.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks for the pointer, I wasn't able to use `nls` in the end because I had to write a residual function to get a fit, thus I used `nlfb` from `nlmrt`. However, I'm having an hard time postprocessing results. I'm posting a couple questions here and on Stack Overflow, if you could have a look it would be great :)