# Non-Linear Regression using nls() for Double Slit Diffraction

Tags: r, modeling

I am trying to fit a model for the data I acquired in a double slit diffraction experiment on R using nls.

The equation I am modelling with is:

$$I=4I_{0}\cos^2(\frac{\pi d}{\lambda }\frac{x}{l})[\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi a}{\lambda }\frac{x}{l})}{\frac{\pi a}{\lambda }\frac{x}{l}}]^2$$

where $a$ is the slit width, $d$ is the slit separation, $l$ is the distance between slit and screen, $\lambda$ is wavelength of the laser, $I_0$ is the brightest maximum and $I$ is the intensity.

I am trying to use `nls` to for a fit of the data I acquired. However when I run my code. I am returned with the following error.

```
YoungFormula <- as.formula(I~4*A*(cos((pi/(W*L))*d*x))^2*((sin(pi/(W*L))*a*x)/(pi/(W*L))*a*x)^2)
nls(YoungFormula, data = data, start = list(A=2730, W=656*10^-9, d=390*10^-6, L=0.5, a=109*10^-6))
```

```
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

My understanding is that my start values are not good enough. However, I know the values of all my parameters. So how should I be doing this? Or is `nls` not appropriate for what I am trying to achieve?

The data I am using is:

```
    mm     mV
1  0.00  106.0
2  0.20  102.5
3  0.40  186.1
4  0.60  333.0
5  0.80  279.0
6  1.00  108.0
7  1.20  379.0
8  1.40  919.0
9  1.45  930.0
10 1.50  891.0
11 1.60  753.0
12 1.80  112.0
13 2.00  528.0
14 2.20 1698.0
15 2.25 1756.0
16 2.30 1722.0
17 2.40 1357.0
18 2.60  115.0
19 2.80  691.0
20 3.00 2290.0
21 3.10 2450.0
22 3.15 2200.0
23 3.20 1830.0
24 3.40  213.0
25 3.60 1009.0
26 3.80 2620.0
27 3.90 2730.0
28 4.00 2230.0
29 4.20  191.9
30 4.40  541.0
31 4.60 2260.0
32 4.70 2490.0
33 4.80 2130.0
34 5.00  488.0
35 5.20  357.0
36 5.40 1693.0
37 5.50 1916.0
38 5.60 1704.0
39 5.80  444.0
40 6.00  177.0
41 6.20  902.0
42 6.30 1114.0
43 6.40 1001.0
44 6.60  610.0
45 6.80   96.6
46 7.00  210.0
47 7.20  426.0
48 7.40  255.0
49 7.60   31.7
50 7.80   75.8
51 8.00   67.2
```

Comment: You should clarify that, in your equation, $I$ is your response (the second column in your data ) and $x$ is the single predictor (the first column of your data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nls` tries to find the vector $\theta^*=(I_0^*,\lambda^*,d^*,l^*,a^*)$ which minimizes the residual sum of squares

$$RSS=\sum_{i=1}^N(I_i-4I_{0}\cos^2(\frac{\pi d}{\lambda }\frac{x_i}{l})[\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi a}{\lambda }\frac{x_i}{l})}{\frac{\pi a}{\lambda }\frac{x_i}{l}}]^2)^2$$

where $\{(x_i,I_i)\}_{i=1}^N=X$ is your data set (thus $N=51$ in your case), also called *design matrix* when written this way, i.e., when each row is an experimental test and each column is a variable measured during that test. The reason why this is the objective function of `nls`, is that the vector $\theta^*$ which minimizes $RSS$ is also the MLE estimate of $\theta$, given that the model is correctly specified, the errors are Gaussian and the data are iid.

To minimize the $RSS$, `nls` starts from the initial vector $\theta_0=(I_0^0,\lambda^0,d^0,l^0,a^0)$ you supplied, and it updates it iteratively using the Gauss-Newton algorithm. This algorithm uses the gradient of your model, i.e., the vector 
$$\nabla I(\theta)=\left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial I_0}(\theta),\frac{\partial I}{\partial \lambda}(\theta),\frac{\partial I}{\partial d}(\theta),\frac{\partial I}{\partial l}(\theta),\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}(\theta)\right)$$

evaluated for each row of $X$. You thus obtain an $N\times5$ matrix $J(\theta)$. This error message

```
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

is telling you that $J(\theta)^TJ(\theta)$ (which is a $5\times5$ matrix, thus it has a determinant) is singular (the determinant is 0) when evaluated for $\theta=\theta_0$. In this case the algorithm can't start. This singularity may either be real (one of the columns of $J(\theta_0)$ is a linear combination of the others) or due to numerical errors (you have some fairly small parameter values and a lot of ratios, so maybe something is underflowing/overflowing). You can have a look at $J(\theta_0)$ and $J(\theta_0)^TJ(\theta_0)$ to understand what's going on.

I think you will find out that fundamental error with your model is that it's not *identifiable*, because the parameters $\lambda$ and $l$ always appear as the product $\lambda l$. Thus, any combination of $\lambda$ and $l$ such that $\lambda l=k$ will give the same $RSS$. For example, if $k=1e-8$, both $(\lambda=1e-9,l=10)$ and $(\lambda=1e-10,l=100)$ will give the same $RSS$ (all other parameters being equal). Try reparametrizing your model, i.e., rewriting it in terms of the product of $\lambda$ and $l$:

$$I=4I_{0}\cos^2(\frac{\pi d x}{k})[\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi a x}{k})}{\frac{\pi a x}{k}}]^2$$

Not only this solves the identifiability problem, but it also reduces its dimensionality, making computations faster. However, as a physicist you might not like this solution: $k$ doesn't have a clear physical interpretation. If that's an issue for you, there's another reparametrization which gives you physically meaningful parameters *and* an identifiable model: just substitute $\frac{d}{l}=d'$ and $\frac{a}{l}=a'$ in the original model, getting

$$I=4I_{0}\cos^2(\frac{\pi d' x}{\lambda})[\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi a' x}{\lambda})}{\frac{\pi a' x}{\lambda}}]^2$$

Now $d'$ and $a'$ can be interpreted as nondimensional length scales specifying the geometry of your problem.

If, after making the model identifiable, you still have starting issues, you can try different starting vectors (maybe try a few random ones). However, in general my experience with `nls` is that it's not very robust. You may want to look at others/complementary tools such as `nls2`, `nlstools`, `nlmrt`. See questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511278/nls-curve-fit-singular-matrix-error/42513058

[Methods For Estimating Trend in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57456/methods-for-estimating-trend-in-r/57460#57460)

[Fit model to density function by regression: improvements?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261010/fit-model-to-density-function-by-regression-improvements/261293#261293)

for guidance on these tools. An added bonus of using `nlmrt` is that it allows you to specify upper and lower bounds for your parameters, thus improving the  chance of convergence of your Nonlinear Least Squares algorithm. If you specify such bounds in `nls`, they are ignored, unless you set `algorithm = "port"`, but that's not a good idea (see `?nls`).

Comment: @user167923 you're welcome. If this answers your question, you may click on the greyed-out tick symbol on the top-left of the question (just below the question score) to accept my answer.